# Reading the last 5 SMS received from a particular number on a particular date

Tags: android, sms

I am wondering how to read last five SMS received from a particular mobile number on a particular date.

I know how to read all SMS from a particular sender, and how to read the last SMS, but I am unable to fetch and read the last few SMS. I tried to read them by using

```
"date DESC LIMIT 5"
```

My code is like below

```
Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
String[] projection = {"address", "body"};
Cursor cursor1 = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri,
                                                              null,
                                                              "address = ?",
                                                              new String[]{phoneNumber},
                                                              "date DESC LIMIT 5");

if (cursor1 != null && cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
    body = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("body"));
    totalBody = totalBody + body;
    Log.d("Registration", totalBody);
}
```

But every time it's showing only the last message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only seeing one message because your code is only handling the first record in the returned `Cursor`. You need to loop over the `Cursor` to handle the rest. For example:

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        body = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("body"));
        totalBody = totalBody + body;
        Log.d("Registration", totalBody);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Also, if you want to restrict the query to one day, you can use a `Calendar` to figure the starting and ending times for that day in milliseconds - as that is how dates are stored in the SMS table - and add the appropriate comparison to the `where` clause. For example:

```
private static final int DAY_MILLISECONDS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
private static final Uri inboxUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

// Months are zero-based; i.e., JANUARY == 0
// Phone number must be exact in this example
private void listMessages(String phoneNumber, int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    String[] projection = {"address", "body"};
    String whereAddress = "address = ?";
    String whereDate = "date BETWEEN " + cal.getTimeInMillis() +
                       " AND " + (cal.getTimeInMillis() + DAY_MILLISECONDS);
    String where = DatabaseUtils.concatenateWhere(whereAddress, whereDate);

    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(inboxUri,
                                            projection,
                                            where,
                                            new String[]{phoneNumber},
                                            "date DESC LIMIT 5");

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Log.d("Message", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body")));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```