# Android get message count from a given date

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am working on a project where I need to know how many messages the user has sent over a given period of time. I have been looking at the SmsManager but it does not have any method to do that. Any idea on how to go about that?

Comment: There's an example of how to get the last five messages on a particular date in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759270/reading-the-last-5-sms-received-from-a-particular-number-on-a-particular-date). I'd imagine you can figure out how to adapt that to your specifics.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it!

Comment: Oop, I just realized you want sent messages. In that case, you'll need to change the URI to `"content://sms/sent"`, and drop the `whereAddress` part.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I appreciate it